# Combining two (or more) SQL results dynamically with PHP?

Tags: php, sql

I've gone through several similar questions, none seem to deal with this type of problem.

I want to select all posts from people who are friends, and then organised them. All my approaches I tried so far have done it friend-by-friend, which is annoying since it doesn't show you newest posts at the top.

Here's how my database is structured, I left out any irrelevant details:

Users table:

```
 UId (Unique UserId)
```

Friend table:

```
 Person1 | Person2
```

Posts table:

```
 PostId | AuthorId | Text | DatePosted
```

AuthorId, Person1 and Person2 all link to a user via their "UId".

Comment: It's possible to get all your friends' posts with only one SQL query and ordered by post datetime.

Comment: I can't, though. I can't just ask SQL about another table with multiple conditons while querying another one.. Can I?

Comment: Please define the structure of `UserFriends`, I'm pretty sure it can be done in one query.

Comment: You want SQL UNION to combine two queries from different tables.

Comment: It could be more helpful if you could post the structure of your tables so that we Can visualize their relations

Comment: @Ashley: Yes, you can. Just add to the question your tables structure.

Comment: Redone the post to make it show the database structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that will work:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Posts p
  JOIN FriendRequests fr
    ON fr.from = p.authorid
WHERE fr.accepted = 1
  AND fr.to =  @myid
ORDER BY p.postdate DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing how you've structured your database, this is a tough question to answer.

In the past, I've done something like this (single query), but my databases were structured pretty well specifically for this purpose.

```
 SELECT * from posts
 LEFT JOIN users ON (poster_id=user_id)
 WHERE poster_id IN (
     SELECT related_id
     FROM user_relationships
     WHERE user_relationship = 'friend'
     AND user_id = 1
 )
 ORDER BY post_date DESC
 LIMIT 20
```

---

Added - 
Not in front of MySQL right now, but for the DB specified by OP, it may look more like this:

```
 SELECT * from posts
 LEFT JOIN users ON (poster_id=user_id)
 WHERE poster_id IN (
     SELECT (if(user_idA='.$userId.'), user_idB, user_idA) as related_id,
     FROM user_relationships
     WHERE accepted = TRUE
     AND '.$userId.' IN (user_idA, user_idB)
 )
 ORDER BY post_date DESC
 LIMIT 20
```

Comment: It's structured like this (Not all tables mentioned, only related ones): Posts is a table which stores the text of the post, the author's auto-increment ID, and has it's own auto-increment ID, and the date it was posted. FriendRequests is a table that stores who's friends with who (Has a unique friend ID, an accepted boolean, and "from" and "to" which are both people's auto-increment ID). Oh, and "Users" which have an auto-increment ID.

Comment: Pretty similar, except for the FriendRequests.  I had more of a User A is related to User B with a bitfield instead of booleans, which allows for more complex chains and one-way relationships.